# ご近所様に配達 - Where exactly this will be delievered?

Tags: pragmatics, semantics

One of the options on Japan Post re-delivery form is **ご近所様に配達**.

> 近所{きんじょ} neighborhood
>
> 配達{はいたつ} delivery

Delivering to customer's neighborhood is a little bit obscure.  Could someone explain where exactly my mail will be delivered if I select this option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading it incorrectly.

> 「ご近所{きんじょ}[様]{さま}」 means a "(specific) neighbor", **not** "neighborhood".

You do not attach the honorific 「様」 to "neighborhood".  You can only attach it to a person's name or a word denoting a person.

Japan Post, upon request, will re-deliver your mail to a neighbor of your choice (among other options).

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you. It's literally your neighborhood.
You can technically have your mail redelivered to a complete stranger, which would totally upset the receiver.

[image: 不在票の例]

If you don't fill the box with an address you want the courier to send the mail to, that would be obscure for them too.
If you choose the option, do designate the place where they can discharge the driver from the redelivery trap at a time.